# Azure Portal - Configure Web App to use Active Directory other than the directory associated with the Azure tenant logged in with?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory, azureportal

I have a Active Directory that I created in Azure. In manage.windows.azure I was able to configure my web apps to point to this Active Directory. This was moved to portal.azure.com:

[image]

Since authentication for web apps was moved to portal.azure.com, I can only select the default active directory, with the following note:

> This is the directory associated with the Azure tenant you are
>   currently logged in with.

The field itself is grayed out, and cannot be edited. I need to be able to change which Active Directory the web app is using for authentication.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that you are having trouble with the new easy auth feature.

The new portal doesn't support cross directory app creation yet, for now the work around is to create a website on the directory where you need to enable the App. We were allowing the dropdown for all the directory on the old portal as there was no clear demarcation in the old portal.

Let us know if creating a new app on the active directory is not working out for you.

[Update]

Sorry for being clear about the feature, Added the ability to configure any AD App in any directory via the Advanced settings on the new Easy Auth UI. Try it out let us know if it worked for you.

Until we get proper Active Directory support for multiple directories in the new portal, the advanced mode on the Azure Active Directory settings on the new portal management portal.

[image]

-CB

Comment: Unfortunately, your answer doesn't really clear anything up for me. I don't understand. Can you clarify what you mean by "create a website on the directory where you need to enable the App"? The active directory that contains the application rules is just a custom Azure AD.

Comment: We are also having problems with this new restriction. In our organisation we are using this functionality to enable our clients to see 'work in progress'. We don't want to add these clients as users to our own AD (and possibly give them access to private resources), so we created a dedicated AD just for this purpose. With these new restriction we are no longer able to use this functionality. Are you planning to re-enable this?